# Roxy file manager can't list images due to loading error

Tags: php, file-manager

Last time I noticed 2 kind of errors when trying to load the list of images in my uploads folder with Roxy Fileman:

**Error loading php/fileslist.php?d=%2Fadmin%2Fuploads&type=image**

and sometimes only this error:

**E_LoadingAjax php/dirtree.php**

So once I have the first error, another time second error after I try to refresh the filemanager window.

After 2nd or 3rd refresh it suddenly works and the files are loaded and shown, but those errors are coming up each time I open the filemanager. randomly they are gone and some time it works, I am not sure what is causing this.

This is the content of **filelist.php**:

```
verifyAction('FILESLIST');
checkAccess('FILESLIST');

$path = (empty($_POST['d'])? getFilesPath(): $_POST['d']);
$type = (empty($_POST['type'])?'':strtolower($_POST['type']));
if($type != 'image' && $type != 'flash')
  $type = '';
verifyPath($path);

$files = listDirectory(fixPath($path), 0);
natcasesort($files);
$str = '';
echo '[';
foreach ($files as $f){
  $fullPath = $path.'/'.$f;
  if(!is_file(fixPath($fullPath)) || ($type == 'image' && !RoxyFile::IsImage($f)) || ($type == 'flash' && !RoxyFile::IsFlash($f)))
    continue;
  $size = filesize(fixPath($fullPath));
  $time = filemtime(fixPath($fullPath));
  $w = 0;
  $h = 0;
  if(RoxyFile::IsImage($f)){
    $tmp = @getimagesize(fixPath($fullPath));
    if($tmp){
      $w = $tmp[0];
      $h = $tmp[1];
    }
  }
  $str .= '{"p":"'.mb_ereg_replace('"', '\\"', $fullPath).'","s":"'.$size.'","t":"'.$time.'","w":"'.$w.'","h":"'.$h.'"},';
}
$str = mb_substr($str, 0, -1);
echo $str;
echo ']';
```

And this is **dirtree.php**:

```
function getFilesNumber($path, $type){
  $files = 0;
  $dirs = 0;
  $tmp = listDirectory($path);
  foreach ($tmp as $ff){
    if($ff == '.' || $ff == '..')
      continue;
    elseif(is_file($path.'/'.$ff) && ($type == '' || ($type == 'image' && RoxyFile::IsImage($ff)) || ($type == 'flash' && RoxyFile::IsFlash($ff))))
      $files++;
    elseif(is_dir($path.'/'.$ff))
      $dirs++;
  }

  return array('files'=>$files, 'dirs'=>$dirs);
}
function GetDirs($path, $type){
  $ret = $sort = array();
  $files = listDirectory(fixPath($path), 0);
  foreach ($files as $f){
    $fullPath = $path.'/'.$f;
    if(!is_dir(fixPath($fullPath)) || $f == '.' || $f == '..')
      continue;
    $tmp = getFilesNumber(fixPath($fullPath), $type);
    $ret[$fullPath] = array('path'=>$fullPath,'files'=>$tmp['files'],'dirs'=>$tmp['dirs']);
    $sort[$fullPath] = $f;
  }
  natcasesort($sort);
  foreach ($sort as $k => $v) {
    $tmp = $ret[$k];
    echo ',{"p":"'.mb_ereg_replace('"', '\\"', $tmp['path']).'","f":"'.$tmp['files'].'","d":"'.$tmp['dirs'].'"}';
    GetDirs($tmp['path'], $type);
  }
}

$type = (empty($_GET['type'])?'':strtolower($_GET['type']));
if($type != 'image' && $type != 'flash')
  $type = '';

echo "[\n";
$tmp = getFilesNumber(fixPath(getFilesPath()), $type);
echo '{"p":"'.  mb_ereg_replace('"', '\\"', getFilesPath()).'","f":"'.$tmp['files'].'","d":"'.$tmp['dirs'].'"}';
GetDirs(getFilesPath(), $type);
echo "\n]";
```

**What I tried:**

- checked if php-mbstring module is installed, yes it is
- in fuctions.inc.php there is a function:

  function listDirectory ($ path) {
  $ ret = @scandir ($ path);
  if ($ ret === false) {
  $ ret = array ();
  $ d = opendir ($ path);
  if ($ d) {
  while (($ f = readdir ($ d))! == false) {
  $ ret [] = $ f;
  }
  closedir ($ d);
  }
  }

I replaced **@scandir** with **scandir** there, did not help.

- in system.inc.php is this:

define('BASE_PATH', dirname (**FILE**));
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_regex_encoding(mb_internal_encoding());

I replaced `define('BASE_PATH', dirname (__FILE__));` to `define('BASE_PATH', (__DIR__));`

Did not help. No more ideas. The dev tools Network neither Console section doesn't show any error.

Comment: You should not use Roxy Fileman anymore. Beside it 's pretty outdated there is a list of exploits: https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-18324/product_id-46688/Roxyfileman-Roxy-Fileman.html. I 'd suggest to take a look on PHP iteratos like DirectoryIterator oder RecursiveDirectoryIterator.

Comment: well I use it with CKEditor, so I need to find then another Filemanager suitable for CKEditor for the future. But for this moment I just wanna fix that issue, because those errors came up just lately. And the editor and filemanager are under Admin login, so only admin is uploading there, not accessible to public, so in this case the vulnerability plays not a big role.